# not concurrent version of map in flutter streams

Tags: flutter, stream

I am using Streams in Flutter. The problem is that `stream.map()` is concurrent which means that it doesn't wait one operation to be performed completely. For example:

```
_sendClientSubject.stream.map((value) async {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(hours: 1));
      // do some operation
    }).listen((value) {
      // do nothing
    });
```

Here, I want the next stream value to wait until I finish my operation. But the case is, instead of waiting for an hour, map is processing each stream value `concurrently`.

My question is, how can I perform the operation `synchronously` in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asyncMap` method from [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package.

```dart
_sendClientSubject.stream.delay(const Duration(hours: 1)).asyncMap((value) {
  // do some operation
}).listen((value) {
  // do nothing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [synchronized](https://pub.dev/packages/synchronized) lock to make sure your events are processed in a "synchronous" manner even in the event of concurrent calls

```
final lock = Lock(); 
_sendClientSubject.stream.map((value) async {
  await lock.synchronized(() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(hours: 1));
    // do some operation
  });
}).listen((value) {
  // do nothing
});
```